# Is it possible to get .class from a generic class?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

How does one do something like:

```
Schema<ArrayList<UnitInstanceData>> scheme = 
        RuntimeSchema.getSchema(ArrayList<UnitInstanceData>.class));
```

Comment: Can we have more information ? What's the greater purpose?

Comment: Not constructive enough to answer. I recon you should read faq of stackoverflow and see how to write questions in a best possible way.: :)

Comment: I am asking a syntax/function question. I dont think this is possibe. The relevant part is ArrayList<UnitInstanceData>.class which is a compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.class` is *runtime* access to the class object.  At runtime generics are gone, having been eliminated by "type erasure".  In your example, all you can get is `ArrayList.class`.  If you need to know the type of the generic class at runtime you must pass a second parameter, as in

```
RuntimeSchema.getSchema(ArrayList.class, UnitInstanceData.class));
```